# Qt, How do I change the text color of one item of a QComboBox? (C++)

Tags: c++, qt, colors, qcombobox

I cannot figure out how to change the text color of one particular item of a QComboBox. I was able to change the Background color of an item:

```
comboBox->setItemData(i, Qt::green, Qt::BackgroundRole);
```

(`Qt::ForegroundRole` had no effect at all, Qt 4.6, Ubuntu 10.04)

and I was able to change the text color of all items with a stylesheet but I cannot figure out how to change the text color of one specified item.

Thanks for your Help!

Answer (score 19):

It's almost like you propose, but you have to change the role to `Qt::TextColorRole`.

```
comboBox->setItemData(0, QBrush(Qt::red), Qt::TextColorRole);
```

Comment: It looks like this role is now obsolete using PySide2 and has no effect. The docs say to use `ForegroundRole` but that didn't do anything for me either. Perhaps this is the reason for Jérôme's answer

Comment: This worked for me in c++

Answer (score 4):

I never tried to do it, but I guess the only way to do it would be to write your own model, inheriting `QAbstractListModel`, reimplementing `rowCount()`and `data()` where you can set the color for each item (using the `TextColorRole` role).

Then, use `QComboBox::setModel()` to make the `QComboBox` display it.

**UPDATE**

I was able to do what you want using the above solution. Here is a simple example.

I created my own list model, inheriting `QAbstractListModel` :

```
class ItemList : public QAbstractListModel
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   ItemList(QObject *parent = 0) : QAbstractListModel(parent) {}

   int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const { return 5; }
   QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
      if (!index.isValid())
          return QVariant();

      if (role == Qt::TextColorRole)
         return QColor(QColor::colorNames().at(index.row()));

      if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
          return QString("Item %1").arg(index.row() + 1);
      else
          return QVariant();
   }
};
```

It is now easy to use this model with the combo box :

```
comboBox->setModel(new ItemList);
```

I tried it and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think that this is the solution, but, if it is handy, in some cases you could use QPixmap-s for your combo box. Take a look at QComboBox::insertItem methods.